# How do I configure sshd_config

Tags: clojure, pallet

So I have an ubuntu vm with ssh set up. Pallet can ssh in, install packages and run scripts which is handy dandy; however, how do I configure my `sshd_config` using pallet?

`pallet.crate.ssh-key` has a nice function aptly named `config` that configures `~/.ssh/config`. It takes a map and updates values in the file accordingly. Very nice but what do I use for `sshd_config`?

I see https://github.com/pallet/ssh-crate but it's not available on clojars and doesn't have a perfect `config` function equivalent. What do I use or am I not looking at `ssh-crate` correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Nov 23 2014, the package is not available on clojars for whatever reason.

Note: Pallet will check the md5 hash after the first write and will error if you try lifting again after manually making local changes. This can be worked around with `remote-file` with `:content` and `:overwrite-changes true` instead of using `ssh-crate`. See https://github.com/pallet/pallet/blob/develop/src/pallet/actions.clj#L398.

To install: run `$ git clone https://github.com/pallet/ssh-crate.git` on the command line. `$ cd ssh-crate` and `$ lein install`.

To use:

Include the dependency in your `project.clj`:

```
:dependencies [[com.palletops/ssh-crate "0.8.0-SNAPSHOT"]]
```

In your `somename.clj` file:

```
(ns my.namespace
  (:require [pallet.crate.ssh :as ssh]))

(def sshd-config
  (ssh/server-spec
   {:sshd-config
    {"PasswordAuthentication" "no"
    "PermitRootLogin" "no"
    "AllowUsers" "myuser"
    "Protocol" 2
    "Port" 12345
    "IgnoreRhosts" "yes"
    "HostbasedAuthentication" "no"
    "PermitEmptyPasswords" "no"
    "LogLevel" "INFO"}}))
```

Use `pallet.api/lift` on `sshd-config` to apply configuration.